# CoordinatorLayout + AppbarLayout + Viewpager not resize child layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a problem using CoordinatorLayout in conjunction with ViewPager and the ViewPager:
[image]

the layout does not resize correctly. Supose that the height solved includes tabs height. So when I scroll to bottom i see this:

[image]

main layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

tab layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/regularLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

child layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea? I saw several posts but could not find the problem, I need that the height of child must be screenHeight - actionBarHeight - TabBatHeight

Comment: It seems a double fitsystemwindow's padding issue. Can you post your layout?

Comment: @GPack check the link "child layout code" on the end of answer.

Answer (score 14):

There are several things to consider when using CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + ViewPager:

- Place ViewPager **Inside** `CoordinatorLayout` but **Outside** `AppbarLayout`
- **Only** `ViewPager` should set its behavior to
  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` put
- Place `TabLayout` inside `AppBarLayout`
- You can also set **scroll flag** on the `AppBarLayout` **direct children**
- set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on both `CoordinatorLayout` & `AppBarLayout` so your scrim color can be applied to status bar

so your final layout probably should looks like this (it doesn't include your *child layout* because I guess it was your ViewPager Page) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here are several resource you should definitely check out:

- [Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#custom-behaviors)
- [Introduction to
  CoordinatorLayout on android](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/)
- [Great sample project by Chris
  Banes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

Comment: Wow great answer, but not worked for me: (1) My viewpager is in a FrameLayout that is in CoordinatorLayout, (2) The FrameLayout has a beahvior because all layouts will be loaded inside it, (3) I put TabLayout inside AppBarLayout but not works, the background color of tabbar and actionbar is the same [see](http://postimg.org/image/x5fhvh1vl/) (4) setting scroll flag and android:fitsSystemWindows not works to.

Comment: I still don't get why you cannot use TabLayout inside AppBarLayout?

Comment: @GastonF. (1) You can set different background color for TabLayout. and if you do that, you have your ViewPager directly inside CoordinatorLayout. (2) AppBarLayout is actually a custom Vertical LinearLayout so Toolbar and TabLayout won't overlap.

Comment: I tried the Chris Banes sample but not working, still can not calculate the height correctly.

Comment: I not use a tablayout inside a AppBarLayout because there is activities that not need it.

Comment: Hey OP can you mark this as the accepted answer ? This definitely worked. thumbs up for the line by line instructions.

Comment: `Place ViewPager Inside CoordinatorLayout but Outside AppbarLayout` this advice fix my problem..

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and perfect solution was add

`android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize`

in layout with

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

---

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NestedScrollview` in your child layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

       <your layout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working, using nestedScrollView allows me scroll down to the end, but my problem is other, i need that the child resize to the correct heigth.

Answer (score 2):

Forcing requestLayout on the pager helped me solve this issue

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mViewPager.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mViewPager.requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest a Link to solve design problems:

[Check tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library)

Use *Main Layout* like

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have downloaded and edited a code but not working for me, i need that the child resize to the correct heigth. For example, i have two tabs, first tab has a simple layout and a second has a recyclerview.

Comment: @GastonF please Implement full tutorial follow steps you will solve your problem. you should child layout match_parent